# Singleton managedObjectContext

Tags: iphone, ios, singleton, nsmanagedobjectcontext, application-singleton

I want to use the singleton UIApplication to access the managedObjectContext of the AppDelegate. But when I write

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext]
```

or

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] __managedObjectContext]
```

it doesn't work.

But this line works fine :

```
NSLog(@"Seeking for the AppDelegate : %@", [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] class]);
```

Do you have a solution ?
Niels

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try casting it to your actual app delegate implementation, like

```
 [(MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
```

And to add

```
#import "MyAppDelegate.h"
```

at the top of the file.

Comment: Do you know why we have to cast, because when I tested the class, it was the same as the cast ?

Comment: Not off the top of my head, no. Did you get it to compile without the cast? It should be the same, really. Weird.

Comment: You can use it without a cast but in this case you will have a warning.

Answer (score 11):

Using a singleton like this is bad practice, and even explicitly discouraged in the Core Data documentation:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CoreDataSnippets/Articles/stack.html

> A view controller typically shouldn’t
>   retrieve the context from a global
>   object such as the application
>   delegate. This tends to make the
>   application architecture rigid.
>   Neither should a view controller
>   typically create a context for its own
>   use. This may mean that operations
>   performed using the controller’s
>   context aren’t registered with other
>   contexts, so different view
>   controllers will have different
>   perspectives on the data.
>
> When you create a view controller, you
>   pass it a context. You pass an
>   existing context, or (in a situation
>   where you want the new controller to
>   manage a discrete set of edits) a new
>   context that you create for it. It’s
>   typically the responsibility of the
>   application delegate to create a
>   context to pass to the first view
>   controller that’s displayed.

Dependency injection (i.e. *giving* the view controller what it needs) is better in almost all situations. It really isn't good to see `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]` all over an application's code because it makes the code hard to reuse, hard to write tests for, etc.

Comment: Yup, that is true. However, I just answered the poster's question ;) It's good to discourage that practice, though.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'll keep my managedObjetContext singleton then.