# NSmanaged context threads

Tags: ios, core-data, singleton, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I use a singleton for working with arrays etc. cross the views in the application.

To initialize the singleton and the `NSManagedObjectContext`, so that I can fetch objects, I use:

```
+(DataControllerSingleton *)singleDataController
{    
    static DataControllerSingleton * single=nil;

    @synchronized(self)
    {
        if(!single)
        {
            single = [[DataControllerSingleton alloc] init];            
            NSManagedObjectContext *context = [single.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];

            single.masterCareList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        }        
    }
    return single;
}
```

When I insert a new object that object will not show up in display functions until I restart the application. I insert new object through this method in the singleton class:

```
- (void)insertNewObject:(Care *)care
{
  NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];      

  NSEntityDescription *entity = [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchRequest] entity];

  NSManagedObject *newManagedObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:  
   [entity name] inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

  NSString *fileName = care.pictureURL;
  NSString *text = care.causeText;
  NSDate  *date = care.date;
  NSData  *imgData = care.imageData;

  [newManagedObject setValue:fileName forKey:@"urlPath"];
  [newManagedObject setValue:text forKey:@"name"];
  [newManagedObject setValue:date forKey:@"date"];
  [newManagedObject setValue:imgData forKey:@"imageData"];

   // Save the context.
  [self saveContext];

  NSError *error = nil;
  if (![context save:&error]) {
      // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
      // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should       
      not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during 
         development.
      NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
      abort();
  }
}
```

My count method is the way I can tell that the new object is not included until I restart the application. The count method is also in the singleton as well.

```
- (NSUInteger)countOfList
{        
    NSArray *fetchedData = [_fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects];
    return [fetchedData count];   
}
```

When calling singleton I use:

```
DataControllerSingleton *singletonData = [DataControllerSingleton singleDataController];    
[singletonData insertNewObject:care];
```

`managedObjectContext` property:

.h:

```
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
```

.m:

```
@implementation DataControllerSingleton

@synthesize managedObjectContext = _managedObjectContext;
@synthesize managedObjectModel = _managedObjectModel;
@synthesize persistentStoreCoordinator = _persistentStoreCoordinator;
```

Why will not my new object show up in ex count until I restart application?

Am I somehow using different threads with different contexts, or different fethedResultsController or different singleton (shouldnt be possible right?)??

---

I added these two lines, which are not included in the genereated CoreData Stack, and it now works fine.

In singleton header:

```
@interface DataControllerSingleton : NSObject <NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate>
```

In implementation file,

```
(NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
```

Comment: In the line `NSManagedObject *newManagedObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:  
 [entity name] inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];` you reference `self.managedObjectContext` but do not show anywhere in your code where you set that property

Comment: @ppilone I have a managedObjectContextProperty and synthesize in my singelton class. See updated question for code.

Comment: I want to find the person who is recommending the use of singletons for data access :)

Comment: @Abizern well I can give him to you if you help me solved this!! Its actually quite nice with a singelton othwerwise....

Comment: Are you observing the managed object context to know when changes are happening? Is your NSFetchedResultsController set up to do this, i.e. do you have a delegate for your NSFetchedResults Controller?

Comment: @Abizern no I dont use a delegate as of now. The thing is, that if I dont try to "initialize it" in my singelton my count method and everything works fine after I call the create new object method. So in that case I dont need any delagates for the other views to know that there has been some changes. The idea was that the singelton do all the manipulation and datacontrol and therefore I dont need delegates.

Comment: So if I remove: NSManagedObjectContext *context = [single.fetchedResultsController 
         managedObjectContext];           It works fine but only after I call the newObject method.

Comment: @Abizern ok, I've been testing around and I believe you are right regarding delegates. I am just not sure how to set it up? Would it be possible for you to reply with an answer with some hints?

Comment: There's a bunch of sample code in the relevant [NSFetchedResultsController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate) documentation.

Comment: How is your `managedObjectContext` property being set? Are you sure it's the same context you're using for your `NSFetchedResultsController`? in your `insertNewObject` method you save the context used by your `NSFetchedResultsController` but use your `managedObjectContext` property when inserting a new object. Are these the same context?

Comment: @Abizern It was me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16594039/core-data-context-and-singleton-data-controller/16596787#16596787 ;) In this case a singleton allows you to manage a Core Data Stack. Why singletons are bad in this case?

Comment: Just pass a context up the stack to objects that need them. It's in the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CoreDataSnippets/Articles/stack.html). Using a singleton is effectively the same thing as calling down to the app delegate for a context.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand from your question, you are using a table or similar.

If you want to update the table as soon as you save the context you need to:

1. Reload the data table `[table reloadData];`
2. or implement in the correct delegate methods of (take a look to [How To Use NSFetchedResultsController](http://www.raywenderlich.com/999/core-data-tutorial-how-to-use-nsfetchedresultscontroller))

If you follow the first option, you can just do a save in the context and call realod data on the table.

```
NSError *error = nil;
if (![context save:&error]) {
  // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
  // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should       
  //not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during 
         development.
  NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
  abort();
}

[table reloadData];
```

**NOTE THAT YOU ARE CALLING THE SAVE TWICE** Do it once. In this case I suppose that `[self saveContext];` does the saving as above.

If you follow the second approach, the data reload woul be handled for you.

Hope that helps.

**Edit**

The delegate of your fetched results controller should be a view controller (the one that contains the table). Do not put it in your singleton!!

Comment: Why not in the singleton? It works :) My views are not "aware" of any Core Data functions or properties.

Comment: @djcj What option did you choose?

Comment: I set the singelton as a fetchedResultDelegate, thats about it. I'm not using a table. I generate pictures and they are then displayed in a historyView. So I fetch the pictures from core data. I updated the question with my updates. I first posted it as an suggested answer since it said: Answer your own question. But it was removed by moderator, which I found weird. Anyway I'm going with this for now. Thanks for the help! @flexaddicted